# Calculus 3: How to find a vector in the same direction as the unit normal vector at a point?r

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Exact question: 
If $\vec n$ is the unit normal vector (with non-negative $z$ component) to the surface $S$ at
$r(\frac{\pi}{4}, 0)$, then which of the following vectors is in the same direction as $\vec n$?

The answer is $⟨1,0,3⟩$,
My question is about how to reach that answer.
Does it have something to do with the formula $\vec n= ⟨-g_x, -g_y, 1⟩$.

Comment: That formula only applies to a surface given as $z=g(x,y)$.

Comment: I am aware, but this question is extremely abstract which i am not used to. How am i supposed to find the unit normal vector from just information they gave me?

Comment: You have a parametrized surface $\mathbf r(u,v)$. How do you find the normal vector in that situation?